# Delete number (/en/blog-2) on Wordpress multi language site

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, polylang

So I've created a multi language (using Polylang) site on Wordpress and I have a blog there. All URLs start with the language slug and then the page/post name. Of course, I have 3 blog pages, but is there a way to delete the number from their slug? I already have the language slug on the url so it'll be great not to have blog-2 and blog-3. It looks kinda bad.

Answer (score 1):

On Polylang support page I found this thread:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/delete-2-to-page-slugs/

Conclusion: you need to have a PRO version to delete the number from slug.

Comment: Ty much, was just strugling with that. There is even setting in polyiang just for it and stated that it is pro feature : "Share slugs - Deactivated - Allows to share the same URL slug across languages for posts and terms."